# Kendo UI Grid with custom JSON Web Server - "Uncaught TypeError: this.replace is not a function"

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a legacy ASP.NET web forms application that has a web service to retrieve data in json. Also the data send to this web service is sent as json. The web service is really an aspx page that gets data as posted form data:

```
json = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Form.ToString())
```

In the Kendo-UI I pass the parameters as follows:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url:  "MyService.aspx",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(GetRequestParams())
    }
}
```

the value of JSON.stringify(GetRequestParams()) is

```
"{"Header":{"Method":"getfiles"},"Body":{"Data":{},"MaxResults":10,"PageNum":"1","FolderID":"14","SearchString":"","SearchSubFolders":false,"DepartmentID":"333333"},"ApiBaseUrl":"/Api3/"}"
```

However, this gives the following javascript error:  "Uncaught TypeError: this.replace is not a function"
If I pass the data without stringifying it first, there won't be a javascript error, but on the server side, instead of the JSON, I get:

```
$inlinecount=allpages&Header[Method]=getfiles&Body[MaxResults]=10&Body[PageNum]=1&Body[FolderID]=14&Body[SearchString]=&Body[SearchSubFolders]=false&Body[DepartmentID]=333333&ApiBaseUrl=/Api3/&GetAjaxData=&$top=20
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can pass a custom data object using the transport.read option with Kendo-UI so that I can decode the data object on the server side without problems?

Alternatively any suggested way of accomplishing this task with asp.net forms in any other way?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out? I'm having the same issue with an MVC project

Answer (score 0):

I did find a work around, but not 100% what it was, since I did this without Kendo in the end. What I can see from my code that I did was:

to pass the data: `data: GetRequestParams()` (without stringify)

In the code behind I would determine if this came from Kendo by this (VB.Net):

```
If (Request.Form("Header[Method]") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Request.Form("Header[Method]").ToLower() = "getfiles") Then
        KendoRequest = True
Else
```

And than get the parameters like this:

```
If Request.Form("Body[PageNum]") IsNot Nothing Then
    PageNum = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form("Body[PageNum]"))
End If

If Request.Form("Body[FolderID]") IsNot Nothing Then
    FolderID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form("Body[FolderID]"))
End If
```

Not pretty, but it worked.